# How to find the closest value of 2^N to a given input?

Tags: java, algorithm, exponent

I somehow have to keep my program running until the output of the exponent function exceeds the input value, and then compare that to the previous output of the exponent function. How would I do something like that, even if in just pseudocode?

Comment: Your last paragraph sounds like one possible solution; which part of it are you having trouble with, specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Find logarithm to base 2 from given number => x := log (2, input)
2. Round the value acquired in step 1 both up and down => y := round(x), z := round(x) + 1
3. Find 2^y, 2^z, compare them both with input and choose the one that suits better

Comment: So what do I display as output? From my example, the program would print out "64"? What value would I print out from here?

Comment: Either 2^y or 2^z - depending on which one is closer to your input. The difference between your algorithm and mine is that here you need to compare only two values with input - instead of comparing all the possible powers of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the looping there's also one solution that may be faster depending on how the compiler maps the nlz instruction:

```
public int nextPowerOfTwo(int val) {
   return 1 << (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(val - 1)); 
}
```

No explicit looping and certainly more efficient than the solutions using `Math.pow`. Hard to say more without looking what code the compiler generates for `numberOfLeadingZeros`.

With that we can then easily get the lower power of 2 and then compare which one is nearer - the last part has to be done for each solution it seems to me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which language you're using, you can do this easily using bitwise operations. You want either the value with a single 1 bit set greater than the highest one bit set in the input value, or the value with the highest one bit set in the input value.

If you do set all of the bits below the highest set bit to 1, then add one you end up with the next greater power of two. You can right shift this to get the next lower power of two and choose the closer of the two.

```
unsigned closest_power_of_two(unsigned value)
{
    unsigned above = (value - 1); // handle case where input is a power of two
    above |= above >> 1;          // set all of the bits below the highest bit
    above |= above >> 2;
    above |= above >> 4;
    above |= above >> 8;
    above |= above >> 16;
    ++above;                      // add one, carrying all the way through
                                  // leaving only one bit set.

    unsigned below = above >> 1;  // find the next lower power of two.

    return (above - value) < (value - below) ? above : below;
}
```

See [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for other similar tricks.

Comment: Since java doesn't have an unsigned type.. does that work correctly for signed integers?

Comment: @Voo it fails for negative numbers, but the problem doesn't make sense for negative input.

Answer (score 1):

set x to 1.

while x < target, set x = 2 * x

then just return x or x / 2, whichever is closer to the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int neareastPower2(int in) {
    if (in <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int result = 2;

    while (in > 3) {
        in = in >> 1;
        result = result << 1;
    }

    if (in == 3) {
        return result << 1;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use 5 as input for an easy example instead of 50.

- Convert the input to bits/bytes, in this case 101
- Since you are looking for powers of two, your answer will all be of the form 10000...00 (a one with a certain amount of zeros). You take the input value (3 bits) and calculate the integer value of 100 (3 bits) and 1000 (4 bits). The integer 100 will be smaller then the input, the integer 1000 will be larger.
- You calculate the difference between the input and the two possible values and use the smallest one. In this case 100 = 4 (difference of 1) while 1000 = 8 (difference of 3), so the searched answer is 4

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int neareastPower2(int in) {
    return (int) Math.pow(2, Math.round(Math.log(in) / Math.log(2)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code for a function that takes the input number and returns your answer.

```
int findit( int x) {
  int a = int(log(x)/log(2));
  if(x >= 2^a + 2^(a-1))
    return 2^(a+1)
  else
    return 2^a
}
```

Comment: Note this is a non-iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bitwise solution--it will return the lessor of 2^N and 2^(N+1) in case of a tie. This should be very fast compare to invoking the log() function

```
let mask = (~0 >> 1) + 1

while ( mask > value )
    mask >> 1

return ( mask & value == 0 ) ? mask : mask << 1
```